# XCUITest wait for a cell with a specific static text inside it

Tags: ios, swift, xcuitest

I have a collection view with some items. During my UI tests, I tap a button, and this will trigger a network request, which, when complete, will insert a cell into this collection view at index 0. Although this network request is coming from a local server, it still takes a second or two to complete.

I want to wait for the new cell to be entered, and check it has the right values. This will be visual confirmation that the functionality behind the button has worked.

How would I go about doing that? I cannot use `application.collectionViews.cells.element(boundBy: 0)` because there is a cell in that position already, so it will find it immediately but it will have the wrong values.

I basically need to query the collection view cells by their subviews. Something like this:

```swift
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "staticTexts['Title Label I'm after'].exists == 1")
application.collectionViews.cells.element(matching: predicate)
```

But this does not work, in fact it crashes, presumably because staticTexts isn't available to the predicate resolver.

The other thing I was thinking is that I build my own version of `XCTestExpectation` that runs every second and runs a handler that would take the first cell and check its contents.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Got it, you have to use `containing` instead of `matching` on the `cells` list, like below:

```swift
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "label == 'Title Label Value'")
let cell = application.collectionViews.cells.containing(predicate).firstMatch
wait(forElement: cell, timeout: timeout)
```